# Is it possible to use powershell to logon https site (secure http)

Tags: powershell, https

I have previously automated login process on a website before which uses http however the same code is not working for another website which is using https (secure protocol). so i am not sure whether i have to do some extra work to logon that website using powershell.

EDIT: Adding code from comment

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "internetExplorer.Application" 
$ie.Visible = $true 
$ie.Navigate("secure.websitename.com/xyz/login.aspx";) 

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;} 

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Attempting to login"; 

$doc = $ie.Document 
$LoginName = $doc.getElementsByName("txtUserName") 

$LoginName.value = "username" 
$txtPassword = $doc.getElementsByName("txtUserPass")

$txtPassword = "password" 
$btnLogin = $doc.getElementsByName("cmdLogin")
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What commands are you using exactly?

Comment: after creating explorer object in powershell i try to navigate to "https://www.xyz.com" and explorer object doesn't contain any values. it isn't null either. after that if i try to read document object it is null.

Comment: I am using following code                                             $ie = New-Object -ComObject "internetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://secure.websitename.com/xyz/login.aspx")
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Attempting to login";
$doc = $ie.Document
$LoginName = $doc.getElementsByName("txtUserName")
$LoginName.value = "username"
$txtPassword = $doc.getElementsByName("txtUserPass")
$txtPassword = "password"
$btnLogin = $doc.getElementsByName("cmdLogin")

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the "https" in the `$ie.Navigate`. I also believe if you pipe `$ie>` to `Get-Member` there is a `Credentials` property that you can use to pass the username and password. I don't have PowerShell in front of me right now but have played with this before with a https site.